# puppet open3.capture3 returns 127 not found

Tags: ruby, puppet

I'm trying to write custom function for puppet.
Here it is:

```
require 'open3'                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                          
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:'clickhouse::query') do                                                                                                                               
  # Headers (somehow are called signatures in puppet)                                                                   
  dispatch :query do                                                                   
    param 'String', :query_string                                                                   
    param 'String', :db_user                                                                   
    param 'String', :db_password                                                                   
    optional_param 'Integer', :db_timeout                                                                   
    optional_param 'String', :bin_path                                                                   
    return_type 'String'                                                                   
  end                                                                   
                                                                   
  # Implementations                                                                   
  def query(query_string, db_user, db_password, db_timeout=3, bin_path='/usr/bin')                                                                   
    cmd_string = "#{bin_path}clickhouse-client --user #{db_user}--password #{db_password} --idle_connection_timeout #{db_timeout} --query='#{query_string}';"    
      stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(cmd_string, :binmode=>true)                                                                                        
      if not status.success?                                                                                                                                                                    
        raise Puppet::ParseError, "clickhouse::query failure: exitcode #{status.exitstatus} stdout #{stdout} stderr #{stderr}"                                                                 
      end                                                                                                                                                                                      
    return stdout                                                                                                                                                                              
  end                                                                                                                                                                                        
end
```

I tried all options for capture3 and popen3 but always get

Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, clickhouse::query failure: exitcode 127 stdout  stderr sh: 1: clickhouse-client: not found

I tried `/usr/bin/clickhouse-client, /usr/bin/clickhouse client, PATH=/usr/bin /usr/bin/clickhouse-client, /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/clickhouse-client"` but always get same result.

Maybe there is some secret tricks?

BTW: /usr/bin/clickhouse-client exists

```
# /usr/bin/clickhouse-client
ClickHouse client version 20.12.4.5 (official build).
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Code: 516. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: default: Authentication failed: password is incorrect or there is no user with such name.
```

Comment: Puppet functions execute on the Puppet server, so you would need the `clickhouse-client` executable to only be installed there. If you want the function executed on the clients, then you need the `defer` function wrapper.

Comment: This ... `#{bin_path}clickhouse-client` ... is wrong when the value of `bin_path` is `/usr/bin`.  You appear to want `#{bin_path}/clickhouse-client` instead (note the extra '/').